# Chrome extension API for filepicker

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is an API for download handling for google chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/

This is great and it works. But I would love to add a listener for whenever a user triggers an <input type="file /> as well. This can be done with some client side script in content_scripts, but I need to do this with the API and not custom logic

There are two APIs that sounds right but only works for ChromeOS: fileBrowserHandler and fileSystemProvider

```js
// WORKS
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener((item) => {
  alert(1)
})

// Doesn't work
chrome.fileBrowserHandler.onExecute.addListener((id, details) => {
  alert(2)
})

// Doesn't work
chrome.fileSystemProvider.onOpenFileRequested.addListener(() => {
  alert(3)
})
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use fileBrowserHandler and fileSystemProvider and want to know an alternative?
What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes. Those two APIs are for Chrome OS only. I’m looking for an API or solution that can trigger on the filepicker that gets triggered when selecting input type=file

Comment: I think <input type="file" /> is upload. Is it download you want to do? Or upload?

Comment: upload. I already solved how to addListener to download. Now I want to do it for upload.

One solution is to use content_script and write document.querySelectorAll("input..") but I don't like this solution

Comment: Why don't you like this solution? Because I don't think there is any other way. So you either learn to like it, or give up.

Comment: Because it’s not utilizing a chrome API. Writing a manual selectorAll.forEach() and adding event listeners to every input of type file seems more like a brute force solution. Not to mention that you have to do this for iframes as well